# how to catch double-click event on the list and on the label

Tags: java, codenameone

The main form of my app has the BorderLayout and a list of pictures is added to its center. User can scroll on the list to see pictures. If user performs a double-click on the list then the list is removed and a label is added and the current picture is scaled to screen-size and displayed via setIcon() method of the label.

Then if user performs a click on the label, the next picture is displayed. If user performs a double-click on the label then the label is removed and the list is added back.

How can I catch a double-click event on the list and on the label?

Thanks,
William

Answer (score 1):

You will need to avoid the `actionPerformed` as this will be called instantly on the first pointer release.

We are considering adding more builtin gestures (e.g. double tap) so this is actually a great time to ask this. Right now the only way to do this is to override pointer released and in the first released create a UITimer (e.g. for 300ms) if another pointer released happens, cancel the timer and call the "double tap" event. The timer code can just call the "tap" event.

E.g.:

```
 List l = new List(...) {
       private UITimer timer;
       public void pointerReleased(int x, int y) {
           super.pointerReleased(x, y);
           if(timer == null) {
              timer = UITimer.timer(300, false, getComponentForm(), () -> {
                  singleTapEvent();
                  timer = null;
              });
           } else {
              timer.cancel();
              timer = null;
              doubleTapEvent();
           }
       }
 };
```

Comment: Thanks Shai. It works for both list and label if the timer = null; is added in the timer code (in case of user just perform a single tap and this timer = null; assignment resets the timer for next time the event happened).

Comment: Thanks, fixed the code. We should probably add something similar to Component itself.